# Passport-saml metadata xml config

Tags: node.js, saml, passport-saml

I'm trying to use passport-saml for authentication in my project. So far I was able to use passport.generateServiceProviderMetadata(decryptionCert) to generate the following metadata.xml:

```
<EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" entityID="passport-saml" ID="passport_saml">
  <SPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
      <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>MIICizCCAfQCCQCY8tKaMc0BMjANBgkqh...</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/>
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/>
    </KeyDescriptor>
    <SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="www.mywebsite.com/logout/callback"/>
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</NameIDFormat>
    <AssertionConsumerService index="1" isDefault="true" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="www.mywebsite.com/login/callback"/>
  </SPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

SamlStrategy config:

```
  {
    callbackUrl: 'www.mywebsite.com/login/callback',
    entryPoint: 'https://openidp.feide.no/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php',
    decryptionPvk: 'MIICizCCAfQCCQCY8tKaMc0BMjANBgkqh...',
    issuer: 'passport-saml',
    logoutCallbackUrl: 'www.mywebsite.com/logout/callback'
  }
```

There are a few changes I need to make to meet the IDP's requirement:

1. Add AuthnRequestsSigned="false" and WantAssertionsSigned="true" to SPSSODescriptor tag
2. Change KeyDescriptor to use "signing" instead of "encryption" and remove EncryptionMethod tags
3. Use SOAP bindings for SingleLogoutService instead of HTTP-POST

Here is the metadata.xml I want to achieve:

```
<EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" entityID="passport-saml" ID="passport_saml">
  <SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="false" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <KeyDescriptor use="signing">
      <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>MIICizCCAfQCCQCY8tKaMc0BMjANBgkqh...</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </KeyDescriptor>
    <SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="www.mywebsite.com/logout/callback"/>
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</NameIDFormat>
    <AssertionConsumerService index="1" isDefault="true" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="www.mywebsite.com/login/callback"/>
  </SPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

Is there a way to config passport to generate the above metadata? Or should I just create it manually? Any help or advice would be most appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a partial answer.
I only know how to solve point 1 (Add AuthnRequestsSigned="false" and WantAssertionsSigned="true" to SPSSODescriptor tag).

AuthnRequestsSigned and WantAssertionsSigned are telling the IdP how to behave and do not need any other change in the SP.
You can just manually add AuthnRequestsSigned and WantAssertionsSigned to the metadata.

Or programatically add them like this:

```js
function generateMetadata() {
    const decryptionCrt = fs.readFileSync(config.crt_file, 'utf8');
    const metadata = samlStrategy.generateServiceProviderMetadata(
        decryptionCrt, // should match with samlStrategy:decryptionPvk
        decryptionCrt // should match with samlStrategy:privateCert
    );

    let xml = '';

    // Convert XML to JSON
    xml2js.parseString(metadata, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        // Add AuthnRequestsSigned to the metadata (as requested by ITS)
        result.EntityDescriptor.SPSSODescriptor[0].$.AuthnRequestsSigned = 'true';
        result.EntityDescriptor.SPSSODescriptor[0].$.WantAssertionsSigned = 'true';

        // Convert JSON back to XML
        const builder = new xml2js.Builder();
        xml = builder.buildObject(result);
    });

    return xml;
}
```

If you are using `WantAssertionsSigned`, then make sure that you set `privateKey` in your `passportSaml.Strategy` so that passport-saml is able to read the signatures.